# group data on monthly basis after categorising in python

Tags: python, pandas

Problem statement : data consists of two columns in csv - date and product
Data :

```
  Date                  Prod
  1/2/2018  7:43:00 PM     A
  1/1/2018  11:41:00 AM    B
  1/1/2018  7:57:00 AM     C
  1/2/2018  1:56:00 PM     A
  1/5/2018  3:29:00 AM     A
  1/3/2018  7:23:00 AM     C
  1/3/2018  1:26:00 PM     B
  1/5/2018  2:08:00 AM     A
  1/5/2018  3:47:00 PM     B
```

I need to return a json data with product as the key and value should be frequency of product on monthly basis

Like:

```
[{"A":{"Jan":"3","Feb":"3","Mar":"5",...},{"B":{"Jan":"5","Feb":"7","Mar":"4",...},{"C":{...}}]
```

i have tried :

```
monthly_series = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='DATE', freq='m'))['DATE'].count()

monthly_series.index = monthly_series.index.month

monthly_series.plot(kind='bar')

return monthly_series
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `groupby` by `Prod` and months with [`Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) and `%b` for first 3 letters of months for `MultiIndex Series` and then convert it to dict in `dict comprehension`:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=True)

monthly_series=df.groupby(['Prod',df['Date'].dt.strftime('%b')],sort=False)['Date'].count()

d = {level: monthly_series.xs(level).to_dict() for level in monthly_series.index.levels[0]}
print (d)
{'A': {'Feb': 2, 'May': 2}, 'B': {'Jan': 1, 'Mar': 1, 'May': 1}, 'C': {'Jan': 1, 'Mar': 1}}
```

If need json:

```
import json
json =  json.dumps(d)
print (json)
{"A": {"Feb": 2, "May": 2}, "B": {"Jan": 1, "Mar": 1, "May": 1}, "C": {"Jan": 1, "Mar": 1}}
```

Comment: json.dumps is not working as the integer value in the dict is numpy int64 type, and it is not serializable. also unable to convert using typecasting

i used  this code to typecast the int64 and it does not work:

for s in d.values():
        for sn in s.values():
            sn = str(sn.item())

Comment: @prj - Unfortunately not understand your problem. Can you explain more? Problem in real data, not in sample `{'A': {'Feb': 2, 'May': 2}, 'B': {'Jan': 1, 'Mar': 1, 'May': 1}, 'C': {'Jan': 1, 'Mar': 1}}` ?

Comment: @prj - Why is used `for s in d.values(): for sn in s.values(): sn = str(sn.item())` ?

Comment: @prj - `is not working as the integer value in the dict is numpy int64 type` so it means you need strings like change `monthly_series=df.groupby(['Prod',df['Date'].dt.strftime('%b')],sort=False)['Date'].count()` to `monthly_series=df.groupby(['Prod',df['Date'].dt.strftime('%b')],sort=False)['Date'].count().astype(str)` ?